# What language are the shaders in Blender written in?

Tags: scripting

What language are the shaders in Blender written in? Like the Principled BSDF and the rest.

Answer (score 3):

Most of them are written in [OSL, OpenShadingLanguage](https://github.com/imageworks/openshadinglanguage), a language specifically designed for shaders. It's similar to C and can be compiled, so that it's fast.

You can find it in the [Blender sources](http://download.blender.org/source/) at

```
intern\cycles\kernel\shaders\node_principled_bsdf.osl
```

OSL is comparable to [RSL, Renderman Shading Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RenderMan_Shading_Language) and [GLSL, OpenGL Shader Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Shading_Language).

Comment: I found some in source\blender\nodes\shader\nodes and they are written in C. Are those shaders?

Comment: Cycles is written in C++ (mainly because it's easier for custom operators). Shaders are also C++, but they have an OSL implementation when you are using OSL.

Comment: I also thought that OSL compiles to CPU code only. But the Principled BSDF is available for GPU computing as well. I'll look that up. Possibly it's available in OSL and C++.